# Can I use pure SQL to return a range that includes one value less than the start value?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Given a table like the following:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE movies( start_time int );
sqlite> INSERT INTO movies( start_time ) VALUES( 5 );
sqlite> INSERT INTO movies( start_time ) VALUES( 10 );
sqlite> INSERT INTO movies( start_time ) VALUES( 15 );
sqlite> INSERT INTO movies( start_time ) VALUES( 20 );
sqlite> INSERT INTO movies( start_time ) VALUES( 25 );
sqlite> INSERT INTO movies( start_time ) VALUES( 30 );
sqlite> INSERT INTO movies( start_time ) VALUES( 35 );
sqlite>
```

Assume I have two time points, a start time of 17 and an end time of 34. I would like a query that returns the rows with the following values: **15, 20, 25, 30**.

What's throwing me is the 15... I know that 17 is contained in the file associated with 15, but I don't want the other rows that are less than the start time (e.g. the 10 and the 5).

Comment: Can you please add your select sql sentence too ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is a little underspecified in my opinion (and working without ids isn't realistic). That said, for your particular example table the following works:

```
select * from movies
where
  start_time > 17 and start_time < 34
  or start_time in (select max(start_time) from movies
                    where start_time <= 17)
```

Comment: did you mean to `select max()` in your subquery?

Comment: I think you really meant `...where start_time between (select max(start_time) from movies where start_time <= 17) and 34`

Comment: That will break if there's no entry with "start_time <= 17"

Comment: But anyway, I think @RedFilter's answer is the answer to the question that OP wanted to ask (but did not precisely).

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT start_time
FROM movies
WHERE start_time BETWEEN cast(17 / 5 as int) * 5
    AND cast(34 / 5 as int) * 5
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/61a69/10)

Comment: +1 Probably the correct interpretation to the question even if OP attributed mine as the solution

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's a cleaner way to do this, but here's my idea on how to accomplish this.

```
SELECT start_time
FROM movies
WHERE start_time 
BETWEEN 17 - (SELECT start_time FROM movies GROUP BY DESC LIMIT 1) AND 34 - (SELECT start_time FROM movies GROUP BY DESC LIMIT 1)
```